# Silverlight textblock binding question + MVVM

Tags: mvvm, binding

I'm trying to create a simple textblock control and I'm trying to insert a property from my ViewModel in the middle of the string.

E.G.  "Hello, My name is **XX**, bla, bla." 
(**XX** is a property from my ViewModel)

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello, My name is {Binding SelectedUser.Name}, bla, bla." />
```

Is that possible?

Regards,

Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar feature has been added to WPF with .NET 3.5 sp1,
but not to Slverlight

See Link: [WPF 3.5 SP1 Feature: String Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/llobo/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat)

WPF Example:

```
<TextBlock 
     Text={Binding SelectedUser.Name, StringFormat=Hello, My name is: \{0\}, bla, bla.}/>
```

As far as Silverlight is concerned, you are stuck to either creating another property in your view model that does the concatenation for you, or creating an IValueConverter

Comment: Hello, I tryied with Silverlight 4 and FWK 3.5 and works fine!
Thank you for your help.
Adrian

Comment: Great, I am not on SL4 yet :(
Thanks for the heads up.